# Determining the frequency of ONLY certain values in all variables of a data set

Tags: sas, frequency, missing-data

I'd like to get a frequency table that lists all variables, but only tells me the number of times "-2", "-1" and "M" appear in each variable.

Currently, when I run the following code:

```
proc freq data=mydata;
tables _ALL_
/list missing;
```

I get one table for each variable and all of its values (sometimes 100s). Can I just get tables with the three values I want, and everything else suppressed?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a number of ways.

First off, you probably want to do this to a dataset first to allow you to filter that dataset.  I would use PROC TABULATE, but you can use PROC FREQ if you like it better.

```
*make up some data;
data mydata;
  call streaminit(132);
  array x[100];
  do _i = 1 to 50;
    do _t = 1 to dim(x);
      x[_t]= floor(rand('Uniform')*9-5);
    end;
    output;
  end;
  keep x:;
run;

ods _all_ close;   *close the 'visible' output types;
ods output onewayfreqs=outdata;  *output the onewayfreqs (one way frequency tables) to a dataset;
proc freq data=mydata;
  tables _all_/missing;
run;
ods output close;  *close the dataset;
ods preferences;   *open back up your default outputs;
```

Then filter it, and once you've done that print it however you want.  Note in the PROC FREQ output, you get a column for each different variable - not super helpful.  The `F_` variables are the formatted values, which can then be combined using `coalesce`.  I assume here they're all numeric variables - define `f_val` as character and use `coalescec` if there are any character variables or variables with character-ish formats applied to them.

```
data has_values;
  set outdata;
  f_val = coalesce(of f_:);
  keep table f_val frequency percent;
  if f_val in (0,-1,-2);
run;
```

The last line keeps only the 0,-1,-2.